# lots of images and ajax, or better solution?

Tags: user-interface, efficiency

I have a control where the user can select a value for the x and y axis from 2 dropdowns, and then there is a 4 by 4 grid (an image) which will show what their selections correspond to (updating dynamically).

So, if the grid is:

```
a b c d
e f g h
i j k l
m n o p
```

If the user picks 2 for row (column is `null` for now), `e f g h` should highlight (using an outline). If they then pick 3 for column, only `g` should highlight. And so on for every combination.

I know I can figure this out by making 25 separate images (one for each square + 4 rows + 4 cols + both null) and then load in the right image using ajax, but my question is if there is a better way or some sort of dynamic solution where I can draw over the image, or overlay another image in an intelligent fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I ended up deciding to go was to use a full image and css to turn it into sprites, put the sprites in a table, and use table borders and JavaScript for highlighting.

ETA: The reason I went this way (thanks @gnat) was threefold:

1. Less bandwidth- pulling 1 image down is much more efficient than potentially pulling 25 (and having to use ajax every time an option changes). Not to mention I don't have to create and store said images.
2. Backwards compatibility. Every browser can render a table with borders, but only the newer generation of browsers (html5 compliant) can use things like the canvas object, for example, if I were going to draw over the image.
3. Simplicity. It's easy to manipulate borders around rows, columns, or an individual cell of a table using javascript.

Comment: could you please expand on the reasons why did you pick to do it this way?

Comment: in the future, I must note that sprites and ie9 don't play particularly nicely.